# Comparing an array to an array with IF statement in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to simulate a portfolio rebalancing strategy with Excel.

Assuming there are 10 stocks each with a target allocation weight and an upper and lower band that is acceptable. If the band is exceeded in either direction, rebalancing is mandated. Each stock has a different weight. I am now trying to come up with an if statement to compare the actual allocation weight (after simulated returns) of each stock with its individual upper/lower band.

E3:E13 is the actual allocation weight after returns of a period.

C3:C12 is the lower acceptable value

D3:D12 is the higher acceptable value.

I tried the following formula to populate a cell with either `"yes" (= rebalance) or "no" (= not rebalance)` based on which the next term allocation will be based:

```
=IF(E3:E12<$C$3:$C$12,"yes",IF(E3:E12>$D$3:$D$12,"yes","no"))
```

I was hoping this would compare `E3 with C3`, `E4 with C4` etc, and also `E3 with D3`, `E4 with D4`, and so forth. Unfortunately, the formula does not create the right output, it often says "no" when some of the bands are exceeded. How could I fix this?

Comment: Do you mean if E3:E12 should match cell by cell with C3:C12? If all values match then show yes otherwise no?

Comment: No, the formula should show "yes" if one or more of the values matche, and "no" if there are no matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? You need to compare a cell's value with 2 other cells, then you can use `OR` (in case you want to match either) ... or you may use `AND` (if you want to match both cells)

[image]

EDIT: Based on your request - you can use an ArrayFormula to get that (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)

[image]

Comment: I need one more step: I would like to have one cell, for example F14 to show "yes" if any of the values in the column C either exceeds its value in the columns D or E.

Comment: Great! That's exactly what I was looking for.